# How to efficiently scatter plot a numpy 2d array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have a numpy with each row containing x, y pairs and I want to display a scatter plot without using a for loop so I used the following approach using pandas:

```
def visualize_k_means_output(self, centroids):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    self.visualize_box_relative_sizes()
    frame = pd.DataFrame(centroids, columns=['X', 'Y'])
    ax.scatter(frame['X'], frame['Y'], marker='*', s=200, c='black')
```

The question is how to extract the first item as x and the second item as y without using a for loop for example:

```
ax.scatter(x=[item[0] for item in centroids], y=[item[1] for item in centroids], ...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to slice your numpy array:

```
x = centroids[:, 0]
y = centroids[:, 1]
```